# jQuery document ready not working properly on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery `.ready` function to add some ajax calls on text input to my registration page's `TextBox`es.

It's all working fine on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but won't work on Internet Explorer (I'm using IE11).

This is the code I'm using on `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(reg_user).on('input', function (e) { ValidateEmailPass(reg_user); });
    $(reg_pass).on('input', function (e) { ValidateEmailPass(reg_pass); });
    $(reg_email).on('input', function (e) { ValidateEmailPass(reg_email); });
    $(reg_age).on('input', function (e) { ValidateEmailPass(reg_age); });
});
```

It fires the validation function every time the text changes in them. Although, I IE, it tells me `reg_user` is undefined which causes an error and it won't trigger these functions.

I'm using jQuery 1.11.3 which supports old versions.
If you know how to fix it, please tell me. I don't know what's really causing this problem. I think IE acts otherwise with `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the "ready" mechanism. The problem is that those symbols - "reg_user", "reg_pass", etc - are `undefined`.  Are those the "id" values for some elements? If so, you should be using jQuery to find them via an id selector: `$("#reg_pass")` etc.

Comment: I have no idea why it works with other browsers, but I'll try your suggestion with id.

Comment: Well it's been the case for some time that browsers (except, until recently, Firefox) have implicitly made element "id" values look like global variables. IE11 may have stopped doing that (because it's a really bad feature).

Comment: I tried using it with `$("#reg_user")` etc, but it won't work either. It's like it is not loading and triggering the `.ready()` function.

Comment: Well the code you posted here - other than the suspicious use of "id" global variables, which even though I don't like it *should* work - seems OK. Are you seeing any other errors in the developer console?

Comment: This line seems to work: `$("#reg_user").on('input', function (e) { ValidateEmailPass(document.getElementById("reg_user")); });`. Though, is there a better way writing it? `ValidateEmailPass($("reg_user"));` won't work properly.

Comment: Well `$("reg_user")[0]` is like `document.getElementById("reg_user")`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(reg_user)
```

with right element(s) selector (ID or Class). You can't create link (var `reg_user`) to DOM element before DOM will ready.

P.S. Also IE11 has some problems with `input` event.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [good read](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php).

> The oninput event is supported in Internet Explorer from version 9. If
>   you need an event that fires when the contents of these elements are
>   modified in Internet Explorer before version 9, use the
>   onpropertychange event.

So instead, you could use `change` - which as the comments suggest doesn't do exactly the same, but it is cross-browser compatible. Also, you should use valid selectors instead of a global variable. This is simply bad practice and I don't know how this behaves on all browsers.